# IPython: How to show the same plot in different cells?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm still new to IPython Notebooks, Jupyter, and Python in general.

I'm creating a scatter plot in a Jupyter notebook using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1024
X = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
Y = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
plt.axes([0.025, 0.025, 0.95, 0.95])
plt.scatter(X, Y, s=50)

plt.show()
```

My question is, how can I get a reference to the plot object so I can use it in a different cell later on in the notebook? Additionally, I may need to modify the plot before showing it again.

Also, I have `%matplotlib inline` at the top of my notebook.

Here are some info about my environment:

- **Python:** 3.5.2 64bit [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
- **IPython:** 4.2.0
- **numpy:** 1.11.1
- **scipy:** 0.17.1
- **matplotlib:** 1.5.1
- **sympy:** 1.0
- **OS:** Windows 7 6.1.7601 SP1

Comment: Sorry for digging out this question. My workaround is to call `fig.savefig` in the new cell to save to an image file and open the image in a viewer (e.g., EyeOfGnome) that refreshes automatically to show the current copy. I still don't know how to show the figure in a new notebook cell. I think it might have something to do with Jupyter internals, particularly the `%matplotlib inline` directive. Maybe it will work in some backend.

Comment: Another workaround is to use the interactive backend: `%matplotlib notebook`. A new plotting command will udpate the original canvas. But I believe this is still not quite what is intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution! Basically you create a figure and the axis with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then use the `ax` variable to draw (potentially in multiple cells). In any of the cells you want to replot the figure, just write `fig` as the last line of the cell, resulting in the cell using the updated figure as output.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804777/5616591) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Try the object-oriented interface of matplotlib  - [matplotlib.figure](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure); you can use the reference of the Figure object created, as required.

- Create a figure object - `fig = plt.figure()`
- Add axes to it - `ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.025, 0.95, 0.95])`
- Plot on the axis created - `ax.plot(X, Y)`

Comment: If I go this rout, I'd be creating `scatter` plot every time I call `ax.scatter()`. Still that did not work as expected in my notebook.