# Jupyter: Replot in different cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'd like to do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([1,2,3],[5,2,4])
plt.show()
```

In one cell, and then redraw the exact same plot in another cell, like so:

```
plt.figure(1) # attempting to reference the figure I created earlier...
# four things I've tried:
plt.show() # does nothing... :(
fig1.show() # throws warning about backend and does nothing
fig1.draw() # throws error about renderer
fig1.plot([1,2,3],[5,2,4]) # This also doesn't work (jupyter outputs some 
# text saying matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x..., changing the backend and 
# using plot don't help with that either), but regardless in reality
# these plots have a lot going on and I'd like to recreate them 
# without running all of the same commands over again.
```

I've messed around with some combinations of this stuff as well but nothing works.

This question is similar to [IPython: How to show the same plot in different cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754107/ipython-how-to-show-the-same-plot-in-different-cells) but I'm not particularly looking to **update** my plot, I just want to redraw it.

Comment: Do not think you can do this with `inline`, it throws away the python-side objects and stashes a png an base64 encoded text in the notebook.  You should be able to do this with nbagg (`%matplotlib notebook`) and you can definitely do it with ipympl

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found a solution to do this. The trick is to create a figure with an axis `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and use the axis to plot. Then we can just call `fig` at the end of any other cell we want to replot the figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_1 = np.linspace(-.5,3.3,50)
y_1 = x_1**2 - 2*x_1 + 1

fig, ax  = plt.subplots()
plt.title('Reusing this figure', fontsize=20)
ax.plot(x_1, y_1)
ax.set_xlabel('x',fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel('y',fontsize=18, rotation=0, labelpad=10)
ax.legend(['Eq 1'])
ax.axis('equal');
```

This produces
[image: First plot of the figure]

Now we can add more things by using the `ax` object:

```
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
h, a = 2, 2
k, b = 2, 3
x_2 = h + a*np.cos(t)
y_2 = k + b*np.sin(t)
ax.plot(x_2,y_2)
ax.legend(['Eq 1', 'Eq 2'])
fig
```

Note how I just wrote `fig` in the last line, making the notebook output the figure once again.
[image: Second plot of the figure!]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent, and the key part that I was missing was leaving `fig` at the end of the cell, getting the kernel to implicitly call IPython.display.display(fig), instead of my attempts with `show`, etc.

Comment: Hey, this works for showing the plot, but what if I want to save it?

Comment: > matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(...)
> Save the current figure.
See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).
I would expect this to "just work".