# Jupyter shows an image / plot, but saves a blank file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am reading an image and saving it. However, the saved image is a blank. I am running the following code to create the plot

```
# Create plot
path = i[1][0][0]
img = np.array(Image.open(path))
plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img)
```

[image: Image created]

This creates the above plot. Then I run the following commands to save this image. Before saving I want to see the image. However , it generates a blank image. What could be the issue ?
I am using Jupyter notebook and have run the command %matplotlib inline as well.

```
# Save generated image with detections
plt.axis("off")
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator())
filename = os.path.basename(path).split(".")[0]
output_path = os.path.join("output2", filename+".png")
plt.savefig(output_path, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.0)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

This generates a blank image.
[image: Blank Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- All of the code related to the plot (e.g `axes` and `figure`) must be in the same cell, not multiple cells.
- As indicated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804817/7758804), calling the figure object `fig` in a new cell will display the image, however that does not seem to enable the code in this question to run in a second cell.
- [`matplotlib.pyplot.imread`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) and [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html) are used to read and show the image.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import maptplotlib.ticker as tkr

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

path = 'd:/data/dragon.jpg'
im = plt.imread(path)
ax.imshow(im)

ax.axis("off")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.NullLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.NullLocator())

fig.savefig('d:/data/test.jpg', bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.0)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

- Code in Jupyter Lab
- The image didn't close because it was plotted inline (not interactive), but it did save correctly.

  - Run `%matplotlib qt` in a cell to switch to interactive - global to notebook
  - Run `%matplotlib inline` in a cell to switch back to inline - global to notebook

[image]

- Raw image for testing

[image]